# Rails "render :text => proc" in 2.2.2 versus 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm experiencing something that I can't explain with Rails 2.3.2.  I've created a new app, with one controller and one action to try narrowing this down.  My entire controller is as follows.

```
class LinesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :text => proc {|response, output|
          10.times do |i|
            output.write("This is line #{i}\n")
            output.flush
          end
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this under Rails 2.2.2 I see the following response.

```
$ curl http://localhost:3002/lines
This is line 0
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 5
This is line 6
This is line 7
This is line 8
This is line 9
```

However, when I run this under Rails 2.3.2, I get this instead.

```
$ curl http://localhost:3002/lines
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

If I hit this with a browser I see only the first line.

```
This is line 0
```

Note that my example code is directly out of the Rails documentation for [render](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000676), except that I reduced the number of lines from 10 million to 10.

I suspect that the answer lies somewhere in the flush() method, but I'm currently stuck trying to dig an explanation out of the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this bug was resolved on 2-3-stable by commit bc2c4a45959be21e6314fba7876b32c1f04cd08a. Check out [the accompanying ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2873-application-reloading-should-be-deferred-to-end-of-request-currently-interferes-with-render-text-lambda-streaming). You can either wait for 2.3.3 (not that far off now), or freeze the current 2-3-stable from git:

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git vendor/rails
cd vendor/rails
git checkout origin/2-3-stable
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: A good thought, but sadly not the answer.  I saw that bug referenced a few times when researching this, but it seems to have more to do with keeping model objects in memory than properly flushing the output buffer.

Comment: I should mention that I did follow your steps to double-check, and I get the same thing that I saw on 2.3.2 as well as edge.

Comment: Would you mind opening a ticket about this on the Lighthouse tracker. I'll make sure it gets looked at.

Comment: Thank you.  I added the ticket here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/2893-rails-23x-render-text-proc-problems-with-output-buffer

Comment: Looks like 2.3.4 will have the fix for this. If I'm reading the ticket correctly, the call to .flush() will no longer be needed.